# identifying the type of clause

Tags: clauses

Consider the bolded participle clause, please:

1. *I work as a programmer, **mostly building ASP.NET applications with SQL Server as the database**.*

What kind of clause is it? Is it a *non-defining relative clause* or *an adverbial clause*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a homework with no OP's research.

Answer (score 2):

The part of your sentence in bold is not a clause, it is a present participle phrase which modifies the noun *programmer*, the phrase is an attribute of *programmer*. See [here](https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerundphrase.htm) or [here](http://www.englishessaywritingtips.com/2011/04/phrases-gerund-adjectival-and-participial-phrases/) as for how to tell a gerund phrase from a present participle phrase.

A clause has a subject of its own. A phrase, be it an infinitive or gerund, or participial phrase, has no subject of its own, the subject (if any) of the verbal used in a phrase is a part of the whole sentence of which the phrase is also a part.

Actually, such question about English syntax do not belong to the Linguistics SE, they are better to be asked at the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) SE or at the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: Can I remove the comma in the original sentence, without changing its meaning?

Comment: @Mr.X No, the comma gives away whether it is defining or non-defining — interestingly and unfortunately, the only to communicate that distinction verbally, is through intonation.

Comment: It's a clause because it has a subject-predicate structure. The clause has no overt subject, though it is _understood_ as "I" (or "me"). We stopped calling such constructions phrases over twenty years ago! The clause functions as a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ The subject is in fact the omitted relative pronoun, which refers to "a programmer". It can be rewritten with no semantic loss to "..., that mostly builds ASP.NET...", the subject of 'builds' is "that", and the "that" refers to "a programmer". However, you are right, it is definitely a clause.

Comment: @William There's no relative clause in the OP's example. "Mostly building ASP.NET applications with SQL Server as the database" is a non-finite clause functioning as depictive adjunct, not as a modifier of "programmer".

Comment: @BillJ My searches of "depictive adjunct" didn't return much that resembles OP's example, but instead resemble something that I learned as "nominal complement of the object". However my search for "non-finite relative clause", as I put in my answer, returns this Cambridge link which includes an example similar to OP's https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite Maybe you can share a link for your classification or write an answer. This question, strangely to me, seems to have been divisive.

Comment: @William, Your paraphrase "I work as a programmer, who (you can't use "that" here, because "that" is only used in "restrictive" relative clauses) mostly builds..." does not seem to be correct, because it is almost equivalent to "I work as a programmer and a programmer (=who) mostly builds...", which doesn't make much sense, because, not all programmers build that type of application. To me, this makes much more sense: "I work as a programmer, one who mostly builds..."

Comment: @Mr.X I'm not sure that's very different. The phrasing may be neater but the basic structure is the same - you're still modifying "programmer", just via the pronoun "one". The original sentence is not structurally different from *I work in London, mostly building ASP.NET...*, but I can't see many people claiming that *mostly building...* modifies *London* in that sentence. I think it's fairly clear that it attaches to or expands on *I work in London*, or *I work as a programmer* in the original.

Comment: @rchivers,*The original sentence is not structurally different from I work in London, mostly building ASP.NET...,*----of course they are different. I can be a programmer but I CAN'T be "London".

Comment: @Mr.X that doesn't make the *structure* different - it just means that a different preposition in required in the first clause (*in* London vs *as* a programmer). The relationship between the clauses is the same. I think it might be worth posting this on ELU if it doesn't get migrated.

Comment: @rchivers, "I work as a programmer. I'm a programmer (ie the type of programmer) that mostly builds..." Does this make sense now?

Comment: @Mr.X does the new sentence make sense, you mean? Sure it does, but it's not the same as the one you originally asked about - the point about the original sentence is that it doesn't contain a relative clause. If you wanted to get as close as possible to the original meaning using a relative, it would be *I work as a programmer, which means I mostly...*. Here *which* stands for the whole of *I work as a programmer*, whereas your *that* just stands for *programmer*. It's still not the same structure as the original though - nothing with a relative would be.

Comment: @rchivers,*nothing with a relative would be*----If you believe in that, then no one can convince you.

Comment: It’s not as mystical as that, @Mr.X. We can see that the construction is headless, which fits with it being supplementary. We could try to get around that by saying that there was a relative pronoun but it’s been dropped, making the construction *seem* headless, but that can’t be right because a) when this happens the verb stays the same (whereas here we have the gerund) and b) the relative pronoun is only dropped in restrictive clauses, and everyone seems to agree that this one would be non-restrictive. All pretty objective. On top of that you have the parallel constructions and the prosody.